# How to resize image Component before image is loaded Android using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to load images for posts (I am using LazyColumn) and determine the height of the post based on image and device width to scale it.

code:

```
Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = colorResource(R.color.post_color)),
            painter = rememberCoilPainter(
                request = post.urls[0].url,
                previewPlaceholder = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
            ),
            contentDescription = ""
        )
```

Everything looks fine but before the image loads post height is 0 and then it resizes when the image loads.

I've tried calculating image height manually but now height of the post is bigger than necessary:

```
.height(with(LocalDensity.current) { post.urls[0].height.toDp() })
```

I've also tried using custom layout:

```
fun Modifier.proportionalHeight(widthPx:Int,heightPx:Int) = layout { measurable, constraints ->
// Measure the composable
val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
val ratio = placeable.width / widthPx

layout(placeable.width, (heightPx*ratio)){
    placeable.place(x = 0, y = 0, zIndex = 0f)
}
}
```

but it seems it has problems with LazyColumn, items get rendered on each other.

here are the screenshots:

[image: working fine here]

[image: long image]

Edit:
I also tried using .fillMaxWidth() now image scales well with the width, but height stays the same.

Edit 2:
Managed to do it (somewhat)

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
```

then

```
.fillMaxWidth(post.urls[0].width.toFloat())
                .requiredHeight(with(LocalDensity.current) {
                    (
                            if (post.urls[0].width.toDp() >= configuration.screenWidthDp.dp)
                                post.urls[0].height.toDp()*(configuration.screenWidthDp.dp/post.urls[0].width.toDp())
                            else post.urls[0].height.toDp())
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `Layout` Composable

It will give access to the constraints of the parent, then you can set the size of a single item relative to it. Add the layout at the highest level of hierarchy to get the entire screen as the parent. Then the constraints you get are actual screen dimensions. Take the layouts in compose codelab for a complete understanding